# Gulp doesn't copy all files as expected

Tags: javascript, gulp

I tried to create a gulpfile.js for my personal website project. I've never done this before but with a little 'trial and error' it now works in an acceptable way.

The only thing that doesn't work even after 1000 modifications is simple copying files and folders.

```
var files = {
  data_src : [
    './files.json',
    'data/**/*.*'
  ],
  distribution_dest : '_distribution'
};

gulp.task('copy-data', function() {
  gulp.src(files.data_src, { base: './' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(files.distribution_dest))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Data copied for distribution!'}));
});
```

This should copy all sub-folders and files to the `gulp.dest`. But it copies only half of them, some folders will be ignored even if I change their names etc. (no special characters, same subfolder structure as the once that got copied correctly ...) - nothing worked. I just can't see any pattern in this.

There is no error message while running gulp. Nothing that would help me find the error.

Why are some folders or files excluded from copying?

---

I use `base` to keep the folder / sub-folder structure; tried with and without 'base' -> no effects on the copying process.

I also changed the position of the 'copy-data' task in the run-list. Actually it's the first task to run. There seems to be no change in behavior no matter if it's the first or the last one.

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.run('copy-data', 'custom-sass', 'framework-sass', 'custom-js', 'framework-js', 'replace-tags', 'browser-sync');
    ... some watches ...
});
```

The structure of the data folder looks like these:

```
./data
   |-doc
   |---content
   |---template
   |-img
   |---chart
   |---icon
   |---logo
   |---pattern
   |---people
   |---photo
   |---symbol
   |-----brandklassen
   |-----brandschutzzeichen
   |-----gebotszeichen
   |-----gefahrensymbole
   |-----rettungszeichen
   |-----verbotszeichen
   |-----verkehrsrechtzeichen
   |-----warnzeichen
   |---wallpaper
```

`/data/doc` and all subfolders are ok.
`/data/img/chart` to `/data/img/people` are also ok.

Within `/data/img/photo` only 14 out of 21 images are copied.
`/data/img/symbol` with sub-folders and `/data/img/wallpaper` were ignored completely.

Comment: if 'base' is the root, you shouldn't need that option.  It may be that one of your selection patterns is incorrect. Can you give us some idea of the folder structure?

Comment: Do you run any other tasks before `copy-data` task?

Comment: Encountered the same problem. This helped, thanks.

Comment: You should add the above as the answer below and check the answered box.

Comment: Are you copying files without extensions? Your current glob only captures files with extensions. Try using `'./data/**/*'` instead.

Comment: Don't know why, But in these cases i search for gulp plugins because gulp functionalities are sometimes weird for me. Use gulp-copy.

Comment: If you have a solution, feel free to answer your own question and accept the answer :)

Comment: You mentioned not seeing errors. Something I use is `gutil = require('gulp-util');` => https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util so that you can do something like `.pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))`; I'm not sure if it would have helped you find your answer, but it is a good thing to know about.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**SOLVED IT MYSELF!** The problem was caused by async operating tasks. Adding a `return` forced gulp to complete the copying process before continuing!

```
gulp.task('copy-data', function() {
    return gulp.src(files.data_src, { base: './' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(files.distribution_dest))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Data copied for distribution!'}))
});
```

Now all images will be copied!

Comment: Great! Thanks Its really helpful